# Pre-roll ads / sponsored links not showing up with YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api

The dev team at my company has implemented a YouTube API Client using the IFrame API (HTML5/JS YouTube player) and the YouTube Data API.

I would like to check our compliance with YouTube's API ToS, and something bugs me: no sponsored videos show up in search results and we get no pre-roll nor interstitial ads when playing back any of the videos fetched through the API.

Is this normal behaviour ? Have other developers noticed this ?

I worry that something may be "wrong" in our implementation that would unbeknownst to us obscure YouTube's monetisation means and put us at odds with the ToS. (our implementation is somewhat atypical - see below)

I noticed that YouTube's official developer demos on the API website don't show any ads either - e.g. here :
https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/demos.html#/topic

Any hints ?

/Guilhem

Notes on our implementation:

In terms of functionality, it pretty much does what the above "topic" demo does.

In terms of design : we have implemented a fairly basic YouTube API client web page that embeds the HTML5 player from YouTube, running on our own fork of QtWebkit browser engine on embedded Linux. The underlying hardware is low-perf TV set-top boxes that cannot meet YouTube's requirements for their YTTV HTML5 app (formerly known as Leanback). The webpage is dynamically generated on our server by fetching YouTube's most popular categories through the YouTube Data API. Search is also implemented through the Youtube Data API. API query results are cached on our server tto optimise quota usage.

Comment: **YouTube** creators can not include promotions, sponsorships or other advertisements for third party sponsors or advertisers in their videos where YouTube offers a comparable ad format, including but not limited to video ads (pre, mid and post rolls) image overlays and video bumpers. This is a violation in their ToS. YouTube reserves the right to disable monetization and/or remove videos with such unauthorized third party promotions. Source and for more information check [this](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/8503222-preroll-ads-are-not-playing-on-mobile-youtube-embeds)

Comment: Well, thanks, KENdi ... but somehow I fail to understand your reply. We are not adding anything on top or aside the YouTube player. We just want to verify that it is serving its ads correctly.

Comment: Ad playback depends on a variety of factors including ad inventory, the domain you are embedding the video on, and video owner preferences.